# Linux command to show which ports are being listened to by services

Tags: linux, command-line

Under Linux, which command can show the ports currently being listened to by services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-p` option to `netstat` and `ss` will display the associated process of each socket.

```
sudo netstat -lptun

sudo ss -lp
```

You can also use `lsof`:

```
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
```